# react native: How to set Image defaultSource on Android

Tags: image, react-native

react native: How to set Image defaultSource on Android.

I have read the `React native` 1.58 document. I found the Image props `defaultSource`  supported iOS only.

I need to set the default Image when the network Image load error.

I used to write the code like this:

```
{ ImageUrl?
                <Image style={styles.docimg}
                       source={{uri: ImageUrl}}/>
                  :
                <Image style={styles.docimg}
                       source={require('../../../resource/default.png')}/>
              }
```

Now there is a problem. When the URL is a string type, but it isn't a correct network Image. As the URL is `true` then the Image will show nothing.

I saw the Image props `onError` maybe solve my issue.

I need to set the placeholder Image.

Comment: What do you mean by 'isn't correct network Image', what string comes when the network image is invalid. Give example for invalid url string.

Comment: @RaviRaj The Network Image URL is a wrong path. I need to do something when the network Image URL is wrong, for example, show the placeholder image.

Comment: @RaviRaj answer is useful but you should only manipulate the state onError. 
onError={ () => this.setState({ showDefault: true }) }

Answer (score 17):

I have tried using **@Ravi Raj**'s answer but seems not related to failure on loading image.
Beside the answer will make the image keep flashing between the default and actual image. ( The error that **@vzhen** met )

Therefore I have developed based on his answer and generated this component. See if this suits you ;)

`progressive-image.js` - Component `<ProgressiveImage/>`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Image } from 'react-native';

export default class ProgressiveImage extends Component {
  state = { showDefault: true, error: false };

  render() {
    var image = this.state.showDefault ? require('loading.png') : ( this.state.error ? require('error.png') : { uri: this.props.uri } );

    return (
      <Image style={this.props.style} 
             source={image} 
             onLoadEnd={() => this.setState({showDefault: false})} 
             onError={() => this.setState({error: true})}
             resizeMode={this.props.resizeMode}/>
    );
  }
}
```

Then import and call the component like this:

```
import ProgressiveImage from './progressive-image';

<ProgressiveImage style={{width: 100, height: 100}} 
                  uri={'http://abc.def/ghi.jpg'} 
                  resizeMode='contain'/>
```

Hope this answer can help you ;)

Comment: I am using a FlatList in which some images are coming as white(error) and some are coming. I tried your solution but it is not working as expected.

Answer (score 10):

You just try this and hope it works...

```
// initially showDefault will be false
var icon = this.state.showDefault ? require('../../../resource/default.png') : {uri: ImageUrl};

return(
  <Image
    style={styles.docimg}
    source={icon}
    onLoadStart={() => this.setState({showDefault: true})}  
    onLoad={() => this.setState({showDefault: false})}
  />
)
```

> Setting showDefault = false in onLoad() should not trigger url
>   fetch again since images are cached by default in android and IOS.

Comment: When `onLoad trigger showDefault: false` my images keep flashing between default image and actualy image. Any idea?

Comment: @vzhen I have the similar error like what you have met. Please see the answer below to see if it suits you. Cheers! ;)

Comment: @Wing Choy setting the initial state of showDefault true and making it false at onLoadEnd resolve the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Work for me

```
<ImageBackground
    style={{
      width: 100,
      height: 100,
      marginRight: 20,
      borderRadius: 10,
    }}
    source={
      require('../../assets/images/Spinner.gif') //Indicator
    }>
    <Image
      style={{
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        marginRight: 20,
        borderRadius: 10,
      }}
      source={{
        uri: `//Image U want To Show`
      }}
    />
  </ImageBackground>
```

Comment: If the main pic is a png with a transparent background, this will hurt your eyes :)

Answer (score 2):

```
const [error, setError]=setState(false);

return(){

 <Image
              onError={(error) => {
                setError(true);
              }}
              source={
                error
                  ? require("../../assets/images/defaultImage.png")
                  : { uri: imageUrl }
              }

             
            />

}
```

This will show the default image if your network image fails to load or gives an error 404.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#defaultsource), the defaultSource prop is ignored on Android on Debug builds, so if you are looking for a placeholder while the actual source is loading -- not in case of errors -- make sure to test on release mode before implementing workarounds to load it only because of debug mode.

"Note: On Android, the default source prop is ignored on debug builds."

Comment: Dear @kamran, Why you mention me here?

Answer (score 0):

`defaultSource` doesn't work on android...
Please follow the method bellow to fix it:
Dont forget to import `View`, `ImageBackground`, & `Image`

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor() {
        this.state = {
          isImageLoading: true,
        }
      }

      render() {
        <View>
          <ImageBackground
            source={{ uri: this.state.isImageLoading ? YOUR_DEFAULT_IMAGE : null }}          
          >
            <Image
              source={{ uri: YOUR_IMAGE }}
              onLoad={() => this.setState({ isImageLoading: false })}
            />                
          </ImageBackground>
        </View>
      }
    }
```